# batch-split How to make two steps parallel-split

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I want to make a sample parallel step only two steps.

Example:

```
<batch:split id="split" >
    <flow>
        <step id="a-step">
            <tasklet ref="a" />
        </step>
    </flow>
    <flow>
        <step id="b-step">
            <tasklet ref="b" />
        </step>
    </flow>
</batch:split>
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way I can implement it?

Comment: Welcome. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Please provide your full configuration and add details about what "doesn't work".